# Kotlin class visibility

Tags: android, android-studio, классы, kotlin

Почему android studio не дает мне доступ к элементам Game_Activity из других классов ? Из-за чего я не могу кастонуть переменные к Button или другим элементам. Как для примера написал в классе ButtonHandlerOnBottom универсальный слушатель для 9 кнопок и чтобы проверить его работу пытаюсь назначить Textview text с именем gorot , но класс ButtonHandlerOnBottom видит его название , но не видит его методов, но в то же время в классе Game все в порядке. Так же в ButtonHandlerOnBottom при попытке назначить на переменные bt1 ,bt2 и т.д. каждую кнопку запрещает каст , т.к. bt_1 и bt_2 и т.д. это для класса ButtonHandlerOnBottom тип Int , тогда как в классе Game этой проблемы нет и все получается на отлично. 
Видимо проблема в видимости о который я не знаю(это мое первое приложение) , этого всего можно избежать если писать код только в одной activity , но мне нужно написать приложение разбивая код по классам.
Android studio в классе Game подсвечивает import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_game.* , тогда как в классе ButtonHandlerOnBottom - нет. Думаю , проблема здесь .

```
package com.example.ps_4.sudoku

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_game.*

class Game : AppCompatActivity()  {

val buttonsonbottom : ButtonHandlerOnBottom = ButtonHandlerOnBottom()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)
    gorot.text = "sdfsfds"
    val example : Button = bt_1
}
}




 package com.example.ps_4.sudoku

import android.widget.Button
import android.view.View.OnClickListener
import com.example.ps_4.sudoku.R.id.bt_1
import com.example.ps_4.sudoku.R.id.gorot
import com.example.ps_4.sudoku.R.id.*
import com.example.ps_4.sudoku.R.id.gorot
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_game.*

class ButtonHandlerOnBottom() {
  val bt1 : Button
  val bt2 : Button
  val bt3 : Button
  val bt4 : Button
  val bt5 : Button
  val bt6 : Button
  val bt7 : Button
  val bt8 : Button
  val bt9 : Button

  var currentbutton : String

  init {
    currentbutton = ""
    //SAM constructor to reuse event handler
    val listener = OnClickListener { view ->
        val text = when(view.id){
            bt_1 -> "1"
            bt_2 -> "2"
            bt_3 -> "3"
            bt_4 -> "4"
            bt_5 -> "5"
            bt_6 -> "6"
            bt_7 -> "7"
            bt_8 -> "8"
            bt_9 -> "9"
            else -> "unknown button"
        }
        gorot.Text = text
        currentbutton = text
    }

 //       why bt_1 is Int ???????
    bt1 = bt_1
    bt2 = bt_2 as Button
    bt3 = bt_3 as Button
    bt4 = bt_4 as Button
    bt5 = bt_5 as Button
    bt6 = bt_6 as Button
    bt7 = bt_7 as Button
    bt8 = bt_8 as Button
    bt9 = bt_9 as Button

    bt1.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt2.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt3.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt4.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt5.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt6.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt7.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt8.setOnClickListener(listener)
    bt9.setOnClickListener(listener)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

честно говоря сложно понять вашу проблему. Следовало сократить код и привести неисправный участок, так мы бы смогли вам помочь быстрее. Если вы пытаетесь вызвать активити из init, то попробуйте вызвать его из другого места, например из onCreate.

Я прочитал ваше подробное описание раз 5, понял что проблема простая, но не понял в чем она) Пжлста, упростите вопрос до 2 строк и приведите код с тем участком, где студия ограничивает "видимость метода".

Comment: Если кратко , то я хочу создать класс подключить к нему импортом объекты из любой  Activity и работать с ними.

Comment: боюсь здесь нужен другой подход. Смотрите на активити - как на главную часть, и работайте с другими объектами передавая в них параметры. В андроиде все завязано на активити и фрагментах, нельзя организовать (по ООП) работу без них в сторонних классах

Answer (score 2):

Активити это не просто классы, а довольно сложные компоненты системы, завязанные на жизненный цикл и имеют множество нюансов в поведении.

Виджеты для экрана каждой активити написаны в виде xml-разметки, это просто текстовый файл. Чтобы получить из него объекты, с которыми может работать система или программист, этот файл должен пройти процедуру инфлейта - преобразования из xml-разметки в объекты. Преобразование это производится, как правило, методом `setContentView()`, в момент запуска активити, когда она появляется на экране, становится видимой. При этом генерируется служебный класс R, который хранит ссылки на виджеты по их ID в разметке. Когда активити уходит с экрана (ее заменяет другая или приложение закрывается) - она считается условно-уничтоженой (ее существование не гарантировано системой).

Вы не можете обращаться к виджетам одной активити из другой активити напрямую, так как этих виджетов физически нет (инфлейт произойдет только при появлении ее на экране) и их ID отсутствуют в классе R.

Если вам нужно влиять на виджеты одной активити из другой, то передавайте между этими активити интент с какими то флагами состояния виджетов, затем, приняв такой интент преобразуйте их флаги в состояния виджетов или используйте посредников, не завясящих от жизненного цикла, как `SharedPreferences`, БД и тому подобное, где отмечайте соответствующие флаги-состояния из одной активити и применяйте их в другой. Выбор способа зависит от конкретных задач.

PS: не стоит сохранять или передавать View-элементы (и других наследников контекста) напрямую, это прямой путь к утечкам памяти, сохраняйте и передавайте только необходимые параметры и применяйте их там, где этот view инициализируется. Например, для хранения видимости виджета нужно хранить только флаг `true/false` в именованой ячейке. При применении видимости читать этот флаг и соответствующим методом виджета устанавливать ему состояние.

Если вы опишите, что именно хотите сделать, а не ваш [неправильный] способ это реализовать, то, возможно, решение будет более полезным.

Comment: Если кратко , то я хочу создать класс подключить к нему импортом объекты из любой Activity и работать с ними.

Comment: если эти объекты - view, то кратко - это очень плохая идея. Настолько плохая, что ее надо уже забыть, впрочем работать это все равно не будет